# Share a value across all views of my activity

Tags: android, view, preferences, shared

This question is more like a discussion about how you guys would do it.

I'm developing an application that has an Avatar Creation, but this creating occurs across two different Activities.

In the first one the user selects whether is man or a woman and a name, in the next Activity the user has to select his face, hair, clothes and etc.

Since the views for hair and etc changes if the user is a man or a woman how would you implement a way to pass the gender value to all the Views?

I was thinking about using a static member to hold the value so I could access inside my views, or maybe I should use SharedPreferences to do it.

I think using the SharedPreferences is a more elegant way to do it but I'm wondering if there isn't any other better and more elegant way of doing it.

Has anyone thought about other implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its only a small information like "gender" i don't see much harm using "Static" variable(Ofcourse the static variable will become null if your app crashes when its in the background).

SharedPreference will come good if you want the information to be [persistent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)(But i don't see you need this).

One more choice is you do can extend the  [application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class to store the static data across activities.

Comment: Extending Application is really nice, although for this case it seens like It's way too much for the thing that I want...

In the end I putted the value inside a SharedPreference... but I do believe that the static approach was OK too..

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the gender to the next Activity with start activity Intent. Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NEXT_ACTIVITY.class)
intent.putExtra("gender", genderVariable)
startActivity(intent);
```

And retrieve the value in NEXT_ACTIVITY class on onCreate() like this:

```
String genderVariable = ""
Bundle parms = getIntent().getExtras()
if (parms != null) genderVariable = parms.getString("gender")
```

Then, pass gender to all your views and persist the genderVariable on SharedPreferences or onSavedInstanceState bundle. I prefer onSavedInstanceState.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way so I don't need to pass the gender to all my views. 

And yes currently I'm passing the gender from one activity to another using the Intents.

Comment: You could pass the "gender" value once to all your views and implement onSavedInstanceState on each view to handle it internally. That way, when onRestoreInstanteState is called, your views will know what "gender" they were working on. But you have to pass "gender" at least once to them.

Comment: I see it's a good solution :), i have implemented using SharedPreferences and on the constructor of my custom views I read the shared preferences to get the current Gender.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways of which 4 I think are better. It ofcourse depends on what kind of data you want to store.

1. For Lists or hashmaps, using a singleton class would be helpful.
2. Using a static class would help, but might leak memory. You should be very careful and always check using logcat, MAT before releasing your app.
3. Using preferences or database.
4. Passing data as Intent extra (parcelable if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences would be the better way to share some global values across the application.